# Confused about AngularJS and Wordpress

Tags: rest-api

Ok, so I have created a custom post type and installed the relevant REST plugins and I have a working JSON feed.

What do I do next?

Basically, I would like to display a portion of the JSON feed on an existing wordpress page, a bit like doing a `wp_query` I suppose.

Can this be done with AngularJS ? I haven't been able to find any useful tutorials. Any pointers to the right direction would help.

Comment: If you are looking for angular js pointers then this is not the correct place

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't know Angular to give you a hand with that, but I'm seeing this question is related to another about [consuming an endpoint with a filter by meta_key](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/237167/create-filtered-list-of-posts-using-json-data) (by the way, I've updated my previous response with a very simple jQuery-only code to show posts retrieved in a list).

However, if you don't mind an example with another library, I used to learn  my first steps with React (lesser learning curve than Angular), a simple function to show the last published posts in a simple widget.

```
(function ( $ ) {
    var resourceUrl = 'http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/';
    function refreshLastEntries() {
        var results = [];
        var link, item;
        $.get(
            resourceUrl,
            function (response) {
                console.log("Received " 
                    + response.length + " elements");
                for(item = 0; item < response.length; item++) {
                    link = React.DOM.p({}, React.DOM.a({
                        style:{"textDecoration":"none"},
                        href:response[item].link
                    }, response[item].title.rendered));
                    results.push(link);
                }
                ReactDOM.render(React.DOM.div({}, results),
                    document.getElementById('reactor'));
            }
        );
        setTimeout(refreshLastEntries, 10000);  
    }
    refreshLastEntries();

})(jQuery);
```

If you **really** want learn to use the REST API with Angular, I recommend you again visit the blog I've linked to you in the other question, since that lady has an entire feed about [Using AngularJS and JSON API in Your WordPress Theme](https://1fix.io/blog/2014/11/05/angularjs-json-api-wp-theme/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes this can be done. You will have to study $http in angular JS. Include $http in your controller or directive.  Then you can do something like this below.  Page ID 199 is the about page for one of my sites:

```
 var url = config.API_URL + "/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/199";
 $http.get(url)
   .then(function(response) {
        $scope.page = response.data;
   },
  function error(d) {
        $scope.error = true; // use to show an error message
  });
```

$scope.page contains the data from your page.  Then in your html you can show it like this:

```
 <h1>{{page.title}}</h1>
 <div>{{page.content}}</div>
```