# Create filtered list of posts using JSON data

Tags: json

So I have created my wordpress JSON feed with my custom fields inside the JSON feed.

Now how do I display these on an existing page, i.e. show all posts with `a custom field value ="dog"` inside an existing page (like a `wp_query` i suppose).

I couldn't find any resources for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you must allow your custom field be queried from the REST API. Let's start simple with an example from [1fix.io](https://1fix.io/blog/2015/07/20/query-vars-wp-api/):

```
function my_allow_meta_query( $valid_vars ) {
    $valid_vars = array_merge( $valid_vars, array( 'meta_key', 'meta_value' ) );
    return $valid_vars;
}
add_filter( 'rest_query_vars', 'my_allow_meta_query' );
```

So, asuming your field name is called "favorite_animal", for this example, you can query the posts using a filter url like this:

http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?filter[meta_key]=favorite_animal&filter[meta_value]=dog

I'd really recommend reading the linked post explaining the example code for your WordPress backend, since meta_key are by default allowed to used only by authenticated users and if you have private data in meta fields, the naive example given here it's a security nightmare.

A simple way to consume the resources returned by the REST endpoint would be showing a list of posts, inside a widget for example, let's assume a `<div id="display"></div>`

```
(function($) {
    $(function() {
        var resourceUrl = 'http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?filter[meta_key]=favorite_animal&filter[meta_value]=dog';
        $.get(resourceUrl,
            function(posts) {
                var output = '';
                $.each(posts, function(index, post) {
                    output += '<p><a href="' + post.link + '">' + post.title.rendered.trim() + '</a></p>';
                });
                $('#display').html(output);
            }
        );
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Sorry I don't see anything in the link you provided. Also I have done what you said. My question is what would be an example code to show info of these posts on an existing page.

Comment: The link of domain with [example.com](http://www.iana.org/domains/reserved)? It's because is an example of the shape of the URL to query posts according to your example meta key and value. The example code from the 1fix.io linked page it's working and you should try it on your own site. Sorry I don't have a site exposing its posts' metadata for you to test this, but I have verified in a local site only for development. About the example code for the frontend, would be ok a simple example with jQuery? Would you share your site url to offer a working example or can I use again the example.com?

Comment: perhaps a simple example with jquery would be fine !

Comment: I've updated my response with a very simple example, please let me know if you have a more specific idea in mind. BTW editing your own question explaining better what you want to accomplish would be awesome!.

Comment: that looks good.. is this faster and more efficient than doing a wp_query ? Do I need to modify your code to include caching ?

Comment: Faster than a direct query via WP_Query, no. It is faster than loading the entire theme functions/templates/styles/scripts. The REST API allows your contents being consumed (and maybe updated) from a UI totally decoupled of your wordpress site. Caching is better handled by the web server (Apache, NginX, whatever), however I'd suggest you asking another question specific about caching REST API, maybe another fellow would have a better response about that.

Comment: ok so for my purposes, it's just better to do a WP_Query... I thought JSON would be better, but your comment explains things :)

Comment: In case you need to pull contents from other WP sites, but you don't have them (or can't have them) in a multisite network, the REST API will be your best friend ;-)